# Why is kotlin not creating a Required empty public constructor for the fragment as required by android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, bytecode

Example:
Create this file in a sample Android Studio project:
Now copy this to a kotlin file and let it convert to kotlin.

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TestJavaFragment extends Fragment {

    public TestJavaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor!!!
    }
}
```

Kotlin converted code:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class TestJavaFragment : Fragment()
```

Tools > Code > Show Kotlin Bytecode > Decompile. Results in this thing WITHOUT the required empty public constructor for android fragments:

```
public final class TestJavaFragment extends Fragment {
   private HashMap _$_findViewCache;

   public View _$_findCachedViewById(int var1) {
      if (this._$_findViewCache == null) {
         this._$_findViewCache = new HashMap();
      }

      View var2 = (View)this._$_findViewCache.get(var1);
      if (var2 == null) {
         View var10000 = this.getView();
         if (var10000 == null) {
            return null;
         }

         var2 = var10000.findViewById(var1);
         this._$_findViewCache.put(var1, var2);
      }

      return var2;
   }

   public void _$_clearFindViewByIdCache() {
      if (this._$_findViewCache != null) {
         this._$_findViewCache.clear();
      }

   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      this._$_clearFindViewByIdCache();
   }
}
```

This is making some devices crash as it appears in crashytics:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{the.activity.launching.the.fragment}:
> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
> instantiate fragment OnboardingPage: could not find Fragment
> constructor

Also tried with a static newInstance where it creates the fragment with argments from the activity, and it crashes too on some devices.

So what's going on, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have no other constructors, a default (empty) constructor is declared. If you define another constructor, then the default constructor is not created, this may be your issue here.

Comment: Nicolas, so why don't I see the default empty constructor in the decompiled kotlin bytecode?

Comment: But do you have another constructor? If so, then you don't see it because it doesn't exist.

Comment: It may be that the decompiler you are using doesn't show default constructors if there are no other constructors, which is reasonable for a Java decompiler. In fact every JVM class has a constructor, so if you don't see one in the decompiled code, that means it has the default constructor.

Comment: If your Kotlin class looks like this `class Name : ...` or `class Name() : ...` and not `class Name(someArgs) : ...`, and doesn't have the keyword `constructor` inside, it should have the required default public constructor and you'll need to provide more information to explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that explains what I see in the decompiled kotlin bytecode, I'm using Android Studio decompiler. I got crashes in my app because my class had a custom constructor like class SomeClass(private val someArgs: Int): Fragment(). Someone reported me that the app was still crashing for the same reason after removing the custom constructor, but it turns out it was something else.